# jQuery Effect on image when scroll

Tags: jquery

I would like to recreate the same effect showed at http://annasafroncik.it/ on the page of Filmatrografia you'll see that bubble effect on the picture, same in Biografia... how do they do that? Thanks a LOT!!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a jQuery effect, but a CSS3 transform called `scale` - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/buaDv/)

```
img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
            border-radius: 100px;

    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0); 
}

p:hover + img {
     -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
}
​
```

Comment: Yeah but keep in mind that this effect is trigger when you scroll down the page, not when you hover the picture. How do you do that with CSS or jQuery?

Comment: [Finding how far the window has been scrolled](http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/browserwindow) - call this function on scroll and attach some listeners to desired heights to trigger the bubble